# PHP gives T_STRING error when connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Code looks fine, but it throws up an error:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u924861036/public_html/press.php on line 7"

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

mysql_connect(“localhost”, “user_name”, “pass”) or
die(“Could not connect: ” . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(“db_name”);
```

The second last line is line 7, but even if i delete it, the error is same, so there is some error in line 8 also.

Comment: Your double quotes are invalid.

Comment: What kind of quotes are these ..

Comment: Replace all `“` with `"` for one thing.

Comment: @RoyalBg It's side-effect of copy-paste. :)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - I `“`second `”` that. Sorry, I did that on purpose (grin)

Comment: Now the **"RACE IS ON"**, as to which **answer** will the OP **accept**.

Comment: Downvoting this one, if you can't solve simple parse error caused by quotes, then I'm afraid you're in the wrong field of business.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double quotes look weird.

Try this:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "user_name", "pass") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name");
```

And please use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` functions.

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong “  instead of " (notice they are 'italic')

please try this:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "user_name", "pass") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name");
?>
```

edit:

Confirmed, this throws a invalid user/pass on my system :)

Answer (score 1):

Use double or single quotes ( " / ' ) instead of a weird ” symbol

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "user_name", "pass") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

mysqli_connect("localhost", "user_name", "pass") or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db("db_name");
?>
```

Just to make sure: You know that you are connecting with username 'user_name' and password 'pass' to the database 'db_name'? Fixed strange quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Replace :-

```
mysql_connect(“localhost”, “user_name”, “pass”) or
die(“Could not connect: ” . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(“db_name”);
```

with

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user_name", "pass") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name");
```

Comment: That's only part of the answer since he has those strange quotes everywhere.

Comment: @Zim84 Ahh.. I didn't see it. Was in a hurry. I have updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks, it was with those quotes, from copy paste, works now